# How do I see the history of my Jenkins build test results?

Tags: junit, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've got a collection of Jenkins jobs which are all essentially tests packs - running lots of JUnit tests.

I keep the results for 7 days and, with the aid of the [global build stats plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin) and [build metrics plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/build-metrics-plugin), I can get a percentage of the number of builds (test packs) that had at least one failure in the last week.

What I'm now interested in doing is getting the percentage of all test failures over one week, to get a better idea as to how badly the set of builds failed - was it just one test that caused each build to fail? Or all the tests?. Is it possible with an existing plugin?

I know the data is there because the home page of any of my jobs has a graph on the right where the green area represents test passes and red fails, for all of the previous builds. This gives me some idea, but I'd like a figure to report with.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at the [Unit Test History Generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/junitth/) or [Test Results Analyzer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin) plugins.